# Convert projected to geographic coordinates R

Tags: r, qgis

On the one hand I have Open street map coordinates and on the other I have the following projected coordinates from Qgis.

```r
 coords.x1 coords.x2
1      306908   9809006
2      347492   9540309
3      544430   9618657
4      662290   9613788
```

Both coordinates are in the Republic Democratic of Congo. I need to convert the projected coordinates from Qgis to geographic coordinates, because my final goal is to calculate distances.

I tried the following code :

```r
proj4string(data)
data_sf <- st_transform(data, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
```

But both lines gave me the following errors :

```r
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string’ for signature ‘"data.frame"
Error in UseMethod("st_transform"): 
  no method for 'st_transform' applicable for an object of class "data.frame
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that your coordinates are written in the format of a geographic coordinate system used for the republic of Kongo (EPSG:3341 as an example), and that you wish to reproject your data to a WSG1984(espg:4326)

```
#example data (please provide it next time using dput())
data <- structure(list(coords.x1 = c(306908, 347492, 544430, 662290), 
    coords.x2 = c(9809006, 9540309, 9618657, 9613788)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

```
#load packages
library(sp)
library(sf)

#create coordinates
coordinates(data) <- ~coords.x1+coords.x2

#convert to spatial feature
data <- st_as_sf(data)

#set the geographic coordinate system (espg:4326 is now assumed since its used for Kongo specifically)
st_crs(data) <- st_crs(3341)

#reproject to wsg1984
data <- st_transform(data, 4326)
```

If you wish to have the coordinates in a table format you can use `st_coordinates()`

```
st_coordinates(data)

         X         Y
1 14.26357 -1.728190
2 14.62523 -4.157976
3 16.39871 -3.450498
4 17.45939 -3.493481
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it worked. I still have projected coordinates. For example :  c(306908.457766328, 9809005.9289975).                                               Also I replaced in st_crs(tmp) by st_scrs(data) because tmp object is not found.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to project your data to a different crs?

Comment: Updated answer accordingly

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I wanted ! Thank you so much it works !

Comment: Glad to hear! You can mark the answer that it solved your question if you want.